# Select different wsgi script based on subdomain in Apache?

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

Is it possible to change the wsgi script used by an apache configuration based on the hostname of the request? I'd like to set up a system where various wsgi applications can be deployed and then run by simply using a subdomain to automatically map to the correct wsgi script. I'm mostly trying to avoid having to change the conf file every time another application is deployed.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.us
    ServerAlias *.mysite.us

    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite
    #can I use a different value here based on the domain?
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/mysite/wsgi.py

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/mysite>
        WSGIProcessGroup mysite
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting an environment variable captured from the request uri and assigning the WSGIScriptAlias path to that var?

Something like:

```
SetEnvIf HTTP_HOST "^(\w+).domain.tld" subdomain=$1
```

You may have to finesse it a little for your purposes, and you need apache2 to capture regex values with SetEnvIf.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif

Then you should be able to use that:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/mysite/%{subdomain}.wsgi.py
```